# Creating a table view application with searchable details

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am looking to try and make a simple iOS app. The app is mainly a Table View with cells that move through to a detail view. The thing is, I have seen how to implement a search that searches the titles of all the cells, but I can't find how to implement a search that searches through the details of the cells.

What I am aiming for is a search similar to the default Music app, where you type in your query and it shows you the results for the "Artists" and "Albums" and "Songs". In this app it would be things such as "Model number" and "Height", which would be included in the detail view of each cell.

I have looked at implementing Core Data, and even a PList file but none of the ways I have found actually have the search look into the details, but only the titles.

Help would be greatly appreciated, whether directly or a link to a tutorial

Thanks,
Pierre

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you can use NSPredicate to implement a search by filtering an NSArray for objects that satisfy a certain criteria:

For example:

```
NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
     //Check all the conditions here and return the boolean indicating whether "evaluatedObject" should be included in the filtered results (search results). here you can check of as many conditions as you seems fit.
      return boolConditionalStatus;
}];

NSArray *searchResults = [tableSourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate];
```